PyTorch model for regression problem with 4 images per sample with time gap between them
I am using a dataset where each sample corresponds to 4 images taken at a known delay from each other and each set of 4 images has a target prediction that is a number (not classification). I currently have made the model below but it doesnt give good results at all. any advice ?
class SimpleModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SimpleModel, self).__init__()
        
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=4, out_channels=8, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(8)
        self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout(p=0.25)
        
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=8, out_channels=16, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(16)
        self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout(p=0.25)
        
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=16, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.bn3 = nn.BatchNorm2d(32)
        self.pool3 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=5, stride=2)
        self.dropout3 = nn.Dropout(p=0.25)
        
        self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(28800, 512)
        self.dropout4 = nn.Dropout(p=0.5)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, 1)  # Single output

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.bn1(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool1(x)
        x = self.dropout1(x)
        
        x = torch.relu(self.bn2(self.conv2(x)))
        x = self.pool2(x)
        x = self.dropout2(x)
        
        x = torch.relu(self.bn3(self.conv3(x)))
        x = self.pool3(x)
        x = self.dropout3(x)
        
        x = self.flatten(x)
        x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.dropout4(x)
        
        x = self.fc2(x)  # Output layer, no activation function for regression
        return x

Also, the target prediction value is often very small and sometimes much larger such from around 1e-9 to 1e2. i have applied a log scale to the target prediction to reduce this effect to attempt to improve learning but not sure how much it helped.


[...] it doesnt give good results at all

Is that with the validation data, or the training data?
If the train loss doesn't go down, it might point to an issue in the learning pipeline. I haven't noticed any issues with the code you posted, so the problem might be elsewhere. I would first confirm that the model is able to learn by reducing the training set size to just a few samples, and ensuring that your train loss decreases (and that the train score is very high). This would demonstrate that the model is able to learn something.
After confirming the model can learn, if you give the model more samples its train loss will be a bit higher and the train score will go down a bit, but you should start to see that the validation score improves.
Some quick checks:

Start with Adam; it's a good default optimiser
The loss should be suitable for regression, such as MSE or similar
The input data should be scaled
Might be worth having no dropout initially. You can add some dropout back in later depending on the extent to which the model overfits.

Your input image dimensions are around 680 x 680? Try increasing the kernel size of the input convolutional layer in order to capture more spatial information (I think 5x5 and 7x7 are typical at the input).

i have applied a log scale to the target prediction to reduce this effect to attempt to improve learning but not sure how much it helped.

To help discern whether things have improved over the previous run, set the np and torch random seeds and print out the metrics of at least the final epoch. That gives you a reference value to compare between two runs. When running such tests, I wouldn't go for too many epochs, otherwise you can't iterate as fast towards a good solution.
